# How can I make a selected calendar notification behave like an alarm, that is, audible even on silent mode?

Tags: audio, notifications, calendar, alarm

I keep my phone on silent most of the time but would like audible reminders for critical calendar reminders. Short of silencing everything else manually, is there a way to acheive this?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [CyanogenMod](http://cyanogenmod.com). It's a custom rom that has a profiles feature built in where you can define which apps should have audible notifications.

Answer (score 1):

Its somewhat tricky..

Don't go in `Silent` mode using stock settings. Use [Quick Profiles](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.softxperience.android.quickprofiles) app to silent everything except Notifications. Then, hunt down all apps which are generating audible notifications. You will found Gmail, Facebook, Astrid etc. Check settings of all those apps. Generally, they all allow users to set notification ringtone. Access this option & choose `Silent` ringtone for all apps except calendar. Done!